# How to change resource(s) of events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

The handling of resource changed in FullCalender 4.0.

In FullCalendar 3.x I changed the resource of an event using:

```js
event.resourceId = newResourceId;
```

In FullCalendar 4.0 I cannot find the right way...
My current code is:

```js
var calendar_event = calendar.getEventById(data.event.id)
if (calendar_event) {
  calendar_event.setProp('title', data.event.title)
  calendar_event.setProp('resourceIds', [data.event.resourceId])
}
```

`setProp` seems to be not the correct method as afterwards the event does not reflect the change within the grid, only the title has been changed to the new one.

A setter to `getResources()`, e.g. `setResources()` does not exist.

The official documentation on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-data only includes resource-fetching, not programmatically set a new one to an existing event.

The migration guide https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 mentions only the methods `setProp`, `setExtendedProp`, `setStart`, `setEnd`, `setDates`, `setAllDay`, `moveStart`, `moveEnd`, `moveDates` to replace `updateEvent` - resources are missing.

My current workaround is to delete and add the event again:

```js
calendar.getEventById(data.event.id).remove()
calendar.addEvent(data.event)
```

How to move an event to another resource without loading and initializing the whole event a second time?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? You are right that setProp doesn't work, looking at the source code setProp checks a const called NON_DATE_PROPS and resourceIds isn't in it. I haven't migrated yet but this is an issue I will face.

setProps: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/core/api/EventApi.ts

NON_DATE_PROPS: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/core/structs/event.ts

Comment: @AllyMurray Not yet. Currently I'm using the workaround mentioned above. I've just filed an issue in fullcalendar-scheduler (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/514).

Comment: This is now possible with Event::setResources in v4.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing resources of an event has been [added in version 4.0.2](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/514#issuecomment-479348121).

The [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setResources) describes the usage as follows:

By ID:

```
var event = calendar.getEventById('1');
event.setResources([ 'a' ]); // set a single resource
event.setResources([ 'a', 'b' ]); // set multiple
```

By Resource:

```
var resourceA = calendar.getResourceById('a');
var resourceB = calendar.getResourceById('b');

var event = calendar.getEventById('1');
event.setResources([ resourceA, resourceB ]);
```